# Android calendar - querying Instances table does not always return fresh data

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-contentprovider

Title says it all. I use minimalistic code from [official Google docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider) to query Instances table, but it does not work properly. There are several random problems:

- sometimes it returns already deleted events, or it does not reflect changes I made (as if there was some kind of cache)
- sometimes is returns proper data but with INCORRECT instance ID for each instance, so these instances can not be opened with calendar Intent (probably also related to cache, apparently Instances table was not re-generated after editing). Once I force Google Calendar app syncing, this problems disappear

This is my code:

```
Uri.Builder builder = Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(builder, timeFrom);
ContentUris.appendId(builder, timeTo);

String projection = new String[] { Instances.EVENT_ID, Instances.TITLE };
String selection = null;
String args = null;
String sort = null;
cursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(), projection, selection, args, sort);
```

How to fix this problem? It is all very random, and can not be easily reproduced because it happens randomly and only sometimes. I saw [similar topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082986/android-calendarcontract-instances-table-returns-old-values) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012807/android-calendar-provider-does-not-return-latest-data/62573501#62573501), and outside stackoverflow [also here](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/47536340?hl=en) but there are no answer nor fixes, nor hints in official docs whatsoever.